# Create new task definition and remove old task definitions for an ECS service

Tags: amazon-ecs

If I create a new task definition for ECS, is there a way to delete all existing task definitions for a service and add the new definition, or do I have to create a brand new service?

The problem I am having, I am stuck in a long development loop where I update a container, create a new task definition revision and find myself having to create a brand new service, load balancer, target group, etc, for this new task definition. Is there a way, perhaps to tell the existing service to use the latest revision of the task definition instead of having to do all the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by using the 'latest' tag on your uploaded docker image.

Then make sure your task definition uses the 'latest' tag for its container image.

After updating the docker image going forward, you'll need to simply 'cycle' the service. In the AWS Console, you can update the service and simply check the 'Force New Deployment' checkbox in the wizard and change nothing else. AWS will then stop existing tasks and start new ones which will use the current version of the docker image. For non-web tasks this is usually pretty quick. Web tasks take a little longer to 'drain'. In any case, you won't need to create new task definitions this way or update the service except to redeploy.

Force new deployment is also available through all of the CLI and API tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

When a new version of the task definition is created, then open the service and click Edit, then select the new version from the drop-down box, then check the Force Deployment and click the Update button. Note that the new task will be in the pending state as not enough resource; if that is the case then select the currently running task and Stop it.